# Implementation of multiple input in Node-RED

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, iot, node-red

I am a newbie in node-red and IoT, yet currently working on a project.
Basically my aim is to create an alerter system for construction workers.

I want to measure altitude, ambient temperature and the state of the safety mechanism (locked or not). Based on the readings the system should make decisions (if the measurement exceeds a threshold  - send a notification [buzzer/LED]).

The logic is as follows:

1. When the system is turned on, measure an initial altitude (h initial),
2. after a particular period of time (not defined yet), measure the current altitude (h current).
3. The difference between current and initial altitude would be the actual altitude of a worker(h).
4. If the altitude h is higher than 2 meters - send a buzzer signal. If the h is less than 0, calculate h initial and h current again.

I have connected the TI CC2650 SensorTag to the RPi's Node-red and it sends measurements to the node-red as json objects, depending on how many sensor readings you'd like you read. In my case (temperature and pressure) I am receiving two jsons in turn:

```
{ "d": { "id": "b827ebb2b2bd.c4be84711c81.0", "tstamp": { "$date": 1469565713321 }, "json_data": { "object": 21.40625, "ambient": 27.125 } } }

{ "d": { "id": "b827ebb2b2bd.c4be84711c81.4", "tstamp": { "$date": 1469565713328 }, "json_data": { "pressure": 1016.36 } } }
```

I've faced the following problems:

1. I couldn't feed multiple data to Node-RED. Was wondering if someone could guide me how to send (temperature, pressure, mechanism's state[1 or 0] data) to the function node;
2. Regarding the alerting. Basically, to find the actual altitude I need to have two altitude measurements. Means, I need to somehow store two pressure/temperature measurements. Do I need to store measurements data as an array or there can be a better way to deal with this?

Was wondering If anyone could guide/help me with this.

P.S. The clipboard of the flow is quite long so I decided don't paste it here, though can send it if anyone requests.

**the very very raw code**

```
var hInit;
var hChecked;
var h;

//p0 is the hardcoded pressure on the level of the sea
//hardcoded for the current area
var p0 = 1019;

//extract the pressure value and the ambient temp from jsons
tagPressure = msg.payload.json_data.pressure;
tagTemp = msg.payload.json_data.ambient;

//the formula to convert a pressure to an altitude

//here it should measure the altitde (hInit) when the testbest is turned on

hInit = (((Math.pow((tagTemp/p0), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tagTemp + 273.15))/0.0065;
//hChecked is the measured altitude afterwards
hChecked = (((Math.pow((tagTemp/p0), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tagTemp + 273.15))/0.0065;

//h is the actual altitude the worker is working on
h = hChecked - hInit;

//in the case if a worker turned the testbed on 
//when he was operating on the altitude he then
//might go down so altitude can reduce.
//therefore if the altitude h is < 0 we need to
//calculate a new reference 

if (h < 0) {
    hInit = (((Math.pow((tagTemp/p0), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tagTemp + 273.15))/0.0065;
    hChecked = (((Math.pow((tagTemp/p0), (1/5.257)))-1)*(tagTemp + 273.15))/0.0065;
    h = hChecked - hInit;
    return h;
}

//check current altitude
while (h>0){

    if (h>2){

        if (lockerState == 1) {
            msg.payload = "safe";
            return msg;
        }

        else if (lockerState === 0) {
            msg.payload = "lock your belt!";
            //basically i want to send a 1 signal
            //to the buzzer which is a pin on the RPI3
            //so probably msg.payload = 1;
            return msg;
        }
    }    
}
//return msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

While Node-RED nodes only have one input tab, that doesn't mean they can't process inputs from multiple sources.

There are multiple options

One way to do this is to use some other message property to distinguish them, usually the `msg.topic`.

Or to  would be to check which properties the payload has using `Object.hasOwnProperty()`

e.g.

```
if (msg.payload.json_data.hasOwnProperty('ambient'){ 
    //do something with 
}
```

But more in keeping with flow based programming it may be better to split the functions up based on message type using a **Switch Node** to fork the flow based on properties of the message.

You should also look at the Node-RED [doc](http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data) about `context`. This can be used to store values temporarily between messages in order to compare them or use them in calculations.

```
context.set('altitude') = foo
...
var foo = context.get('altitude');
```

Comment: Thank you! context helped me!